# SQL Server - Query to retrieve column names and sum of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having difficulty with a query. I have a table called products with a large number of columns that looks like this:

```
 X  |  Y  |  Z  | ... (and on)
----+-----+-----+
 4  |  9  |  4  |
 5  |  2  |  6  |
 2  |  5  |  9  |
```

Then I want to develop a query that will output the column names and their sums like this:

```
ProductName  |  Quantity
-------------+-----------
    X        |     11
    Y        |     16
    Z        |     19
...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Pivot....

Comment: are column names dynamic or is their list fixed?

Comment: scsimon +/- 10k columns. and thanks for the hint, going to dig into that. RadimBaca, fixed

Comment: 10K? So you are using Wide Tables then. Not commonly seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly UNPIVOT and perhaps Dynamic SQL would be more performant, but the following will "dynamically" unpivot and aggregate yourdata.

Please note that this converts the row to XML, and NULL values will be excluded

**Example**

```
Select ProductName = C.Field
      ,Quanity     = sum(C.Value)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','int')           --<< Change to desired data type
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('FieldsTo','Exclude')
             ) C
 Group By C.Field
```

**Returns**

```
ProductName Quanity
X           11
Y           16
Z           19
```

**If it helps with the Visualization the subquery generates:**

[image]

Comment: John, I love the idea with the subquery. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `yourtbl` you can use UNPIVOT

```
Select productName, SUM(Quantity) Quantity
from
(
select productName, Quantity
from
(
select * 
from yourtbl
)src
UNPIVOT
(
Quantity for ProductName in ([X],[Y],[Z])
)up
)t group by productName
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `unpivot` with `SUM` to achieve the expected result. To create SQL for such large number of attributes I would definitely use the dynamic T-SQL.

```
SELECT ProductName, Quantity
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(X) x, SUM(y) y, SUM(z) z FROM your_table
)
UNPIVOT
( 
   Quantity FOR ProductName IN (X, Y, Z)
) AS t
```